# Attach xterm.js to Docker container

Tags: docker, xtermjs

I'm trying to add a terminal to a web application with xterm.js and its 'attach' addon.  I'd like to just have a process running in a Docker container, and then attach the xterm instance to stdin/stdout for the container.  The [example for the attach addon](https://xtermjs.org/docs/api/addons/attach/) indicates that this should be straightforward using the websocket interface for container attachment with docker.

I haven't yet been able to do this successfully, but it's possible that it's purely a problem with my local configuration.  A [github issue for xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/883) leaves it a bit ambiguous whether this should actually work now, based on changes to the docker API.  Has anyone had success with this using a modern version of docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a docker configuration problem on my side...

Apparently the attach addon (and anything else that would try to attach with a websocket, e.g. docker-py) does not work with the default dockerd socket (/var/run/docker.sock), so you have to redirect from another port or run the docker daemon from a tcp socket instead of the unix one.  You can do this with the `socat` tool:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:2376,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little as to how you proceeded with the same? Any open source resources?